# How can i redirect a not working url or removing the indexing of the url from google search console

Tags: redirect, indexing, invalid-characters, invalid-url

How can i remove the indexing of the url from google search, I have this url, and we need to remove it because it does not work well.

This is the url - https://www.avon.com.gt/cam-home?curnav=Cuidado%20Personal

When im trying to redirect this url it is saying invalid url(because the link has one space between Cuidado and Personal). If you can help with how can i redirect this url from apache web server configuration, will help me a lot.

I think the meta tag  in this case not is the solution because the meta tag would have to be put in the home. If I do this google no indexing anymore the home.

Maybe Google search console but i think it will do only temporary.

Thanks you so much for your help.

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  What code have you tried for redirecting that didn't work?

Comment: im not good at redirecting configuration , for the simple url i am able to redirect as per google help but for this url which is having little different string in the end, i was not able to code the same redirection configuration, if you can help me with redirection, will help a lot to me.

Comment: this url - https://www.avon.com.gt/cam-home?curnav=Cuidado%20Personal is having some question mark , equal to sign and %20 symbol which is making me difficult to code the redirection code for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can request from google that they remove one or more web pages from the search console. Your web page is https://www.avon.com.gt/cam-home, you do not include query parameters appended on to the end of the URL.

Find the page in Google Search Console click Google Index > Remove URLs.

In can then take google several days to action your request.

You do not seem that experienced so if you want to re-direct to another webpage while you are waiting for google to action your request just add some javascript to the page something like this...

```
<script>
window.location.href = 'http://www.youtube.com'; 
</script>
```

If you are feeling more adventurous you can have apache re-write the url on the fly to direct people to your new page, something like this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^avon.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} cam-home [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ /new-page
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for answering, i will try this and update here if it will help. If it can remove sooner that will be the better help. Lets see.

Comment: If someone can help with redirection of this url, as i checked tried few redirection code as per my understanding but that didn't help

source url - https://www.avon.com.gt/cam-home?curnav=Cuidado%20Personal

destination url - https://www.avon.com.gt/avon-cam/personalcare/Cuidado-Personal-lo-nuevo.html

Comment: see simple solution for redirection in my answer, there are better ways of achieving this but this method is probably more suitable for you

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike for your simple solution, actually i am a middleware guy, im not having access to code, im having access to apache web server configuration and looking if it can be directed from apache web server configuration though i have requested developer to try your solution , just want to know if its possible from apache configuration. Thanks

Comment: yes it can be done from apache with a conditional redirect rule or with a conditional re-write rule

Comment: yes this is what im looking for, conditional redirect rule for apache, i tried to understand and implement but im not able to understand those conditions, so many regex are there and its confusing for me actually if someone can help with condition redirect rule. Thanks

Comment: There is an example in my answer

Comment: Thanks Mike, i will try with your RewriteCond and RewriteRule configuration today.

Here dev team is saying as below:

"The redirect from js or metatag isn’t the solution because the url is a variant  (https://www.avon.com.gt/cam-home?curnav=Cuidado%20Personal).
 
because it has variables for the get method, if I do the redirection it would affect the base url (https://www.avon.com.gt/cam-home)"

Comment: I have a question: Can we create the redirection with the  %20 on the url ?

source url - https://www.avon.com.gt/cam-home?curnav=Cuidado%20Personal
destination url - https://www.avon.com.gt/avon-cam/personalcare/Cuidado-Personal-lo-nuevo.html

Comment: Finally this worked, thanks Mike for all your help.

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.avon\.com\.gt$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^curnav\=Cuidado%20Personal$
RewriteRule ^/?cam\-home$ /avon-cam/personalcare/Cuidado-Personal-lo-nuevo.html [L,R=301,QSD]